# Is there a mass edit in Excel that can roll back the day in a date by 1 and the year forward by 1?

Tags: excel, date

I have a spreadsheet with cells dated for every day of the year. My dates are in the following format:

m/d/yyyy 1/23/2013

I need each date (all 365) to roll the day back 1 and the year forward 1.

1/23/2013 --> 1/22/2014

```
     or
```

2/1/2013 --> 1/31/2014

As of right now I have to change it cell by cell.  Is there a way to edit them all at once?  Every date in the spreadsheet is in this format, and needs this change.  Thanks!

Comment: how about adding 364 to each day in another column, and then copy/pasting __values__ back into the original column, or start a column with the new start date, and __fill down__ (should automatically give you the correct sequence)

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. more suitable for superuser perhaps

Comment: @Loopo: is correct. I have voted it to be moved to SU. :)

Comment: Will you have leap years? If so, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. It is called `Pastespecial` | `Values` with Operation as `Add`

Type 364 in any blank cell and copy it. Select your range which has dates and do `Pastespecial` | `Values` with Operation as `Add`

[image]

Comment: Subtracting 1 will only change the day.  They wanted the year changed forward as well, so you'd really need to do +364.

Comment: @techturtle: True, I misread the question. I have amended the post.

Answer (score 1):

If one of your source numbers is in A1, you can use the following formula

```
=A1+364
```

to get the result. Then make sure you use a suitable number format.

I assume that when you say "all 365" you mean there are no leap years to take care of.
Otherwise, use

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)-1)
```

which is good for any date.